# using doxygen for java with Doxywizard

Tags: java, doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-wizard

Doxywizard Doxygen not scanning the packages for java files

Need help on Doxygen/Doxywizard

These are my Doxywizard settings:

Working directory from where doxygen will run:

> C:/Program Files/doxygen

In 'Wizard' tab, the below values are set.
Source code directory:

> C:/workspace/git/employeeapp/src/main/java

Destination directory:

> C:/Doxy-docs/1

In 'Expert' tab, under Topics-'Build' , selected the '**EXTRACT_ALL**'

I installed Doxywizard, open the wizard, set the above values, went to 'Run' tab
and clicked 'Run doxygen', I expected that all the folders/packages inside the 'src/main/java'
will be scanned and a project default documentation would be created.

**Problem**: However I see that 'C:/Doxy-docs/1/html/index.html' is blank and no other pages were created.

If I just navigate to a folder where there is a '*.java' file [say src/main/java/com/app/], documentation is created for
the '*.java' files inside that folder. But as in the above scenario where 'src/main/java' is mentioned,
the tool is not scanning for packages/folders inside for the '*.java' files.

**Question**: Am I missing some configuration? or is this the expected functionality of doxygen that it cannot scan inside 
folder-folder etc?

Note: This link shows the features of doxygen and from that I think it support the feature that I am expecting.
http://www.doxygen.nl/features.html

*Note: I added java tag only because I am using the wizard to scan java files*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued my effort in finding the option to set it,
and came across this link,
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-learningdoxygen/

which mention about 'RECURSIVE'
: Set this tag to Yes if the source hierarchy is nested and you need to generate documentation for C/C++ 
files at all hierarchy levels. For example, consider the root-level source hierarchy /home/user1/project/kernel, 
which has multiple sub-directories such as /home/user1/project/kernel/vmm and /home/user1/project/kernel/asm. 
If this tag is set to Yes, doxygen recursively traverses the hierarchy, extracting information.

Got my boy - its **'RECURSIVE'**

In Doxywizard, found it under 'Expert' tab and then Topics - 'Input'

checked the checkbox against 'RECURSIVE', and selected '*.java' in FILE_PATTERNS.

Executed again, and the whole documentation is on the table!!! [destination dir what i mentioned]

or,

In the 'Expert' tab itself, when we specify the 'Source code directory',
there is a checkbox for 'Scan recursively'. Just check it.